# Get column header label while sorting a lightning:datatable column

Tags: lightning-datatable

As per the salesforce official doc, when we `sort` a `column`,  we can get the  field name by using

```
var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

```
({
    // Client-side controller called by the onsort event handler
    updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
        cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
    }
    })
```

Is there any way we can get the `column header` label?

**UPDATED :**

I somehow found the workaround, but still looking an for the easy way.

```
updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var labelName = '';
        var colList = cmp.get("v.myCols");
        colList.some(function(col){
            if(col.fieldName === fieldName) {
               labelName = col.label; 
            }
            return col.fieldName === fieldName;
        });
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName,labelName, sortDirection);
    }
```

Comment: It's pretty common to have a `v.columns` attribute in your component bound to the `columns` attribute of the data table - that would pretty easily give you the column name if the pattern is used here.

Comment: @DavidReed : Agreed, but `{!v.columns}`will have multiple columns. Column sorting is a single click event. So, I was wondering if `event` has any parameter to find the column label.

Comment: @DavidReed : I updated the question with the possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the column based on the incoming fieldName:

```
var columns = cmp.get("v.columns"), // whatever you called the columns attribute
    fieldName = event.getParam("fieldName"),
    sortByCol = columns.find(column => fieldName === column.fieldName),
    fieldLabel = sortByCol.label;
```

At this point, you have all the attributes from the column header (`sortByCol`) and the field label, as you've asked for.

Comment: Please tell me how to fetch Sorted column label from fieldApi in lwc     
                                                                                                                                                  
     onHandleSort(event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...this.eFileFields];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    this.eFileFields = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.isSorted = true;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}

Comment: @HarshitVermabluCursor `const fieldLabel = this.columns.find(field=>field.fieldName===sortedBy).label;` replacing `this.columns` with your columns variable.